# Adding condition based on Data Validation List in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble with a small excel formula problem. I am trying to use `AVERGEIFS`. The setup of this function is

```
AVERAGEIFS(average_range,criteria_range1,criteria1,criteria_range2,criteria2,...)
```

The catch is that I want the inclusion of a criteria and its range `[criteria_range1,criteria1]` to be based on whether a data validation list is `Yes` or `No`. So for example if the list is currently set to `Yes` return:

```
AVERAGEIFS(average_range,criteria_range1,criteria1)
```

If no then return

```
AVERAGEIFS(average_range,criteria_range1,criteria1,criteria_range2,criteria2)
```

I would use an `IF` function to handle this if I had only one data validation list with `Yes` and `No`, but I have several, three to be exact. So I want to set up a formula that will include a `[criteria_range,criteria]` based on whether its corresponding data validation list is `Yes` or `No`.

I hope that makes sense. I am using OSX. Thanks!

### EDIT:

[image]

In my problem a `name` is chosen and with it the corresponding attributes from the dataset below. In the `average` box below I would love to see the average `value` for rows with the same attributes in John's case its any rows with blue, type1 = 1, AND type2 = 100. This is easy if I just use a regular `AVERAGEIFS` function.

What I am trying to figure out is how I could ignore one of the attributes and find the average for that group. So if I select ignore `yes` for `type1` then `average` would return the average `value` for rows with `color = red` AND `type2 = 100`

Comment: How do those optional criteria1, criteria2... look like?

Comment: They are factors i.e. groups or types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample screenshot it looks like your `criteria1` might look like:

```
"=" & B3
```

I would replace it with:

```
IF(D3="yes","<>ABCDEF","=" & B3)
```

Where `ABCDEF` is any string that does not exist in the `criteria_range1`, so the `<>ABCDEF` condition is always true. This trick should work for every type of data (strings, numbers, dates, blanks).

The full formula for your sample screenshot would be:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(E7:E15,C7:C15,IF(D3="yes","<>ABCDEF","=" & B3),D7:D15,
IF(D4="yes","<>ABCDEF","=" & B4),B7:B15,"=" & B2,A7:A15,"=" & B1)
```